# SQL Server Version Numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, version-numbering

I need to check SQL Server versions as prerequisites for my software. I found a few places that have the version numbers table but they are inconsistent. For example, according to [this website](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions) and [this website](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/FAQs/SQLServerVersionDatabase/tabid/63/Default.aspx)

SQL Server 2008 R2 starts with `10.5` where on my developer machine which I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed, i found the version number starts with `10.50`
Similarly, for SQL Server 2008, according to the website, the version number starts with `10.0` where on my developer machine it starts with `10.00`

On Microsoft website however, I found [this kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) and it says SQL Server 2008 starts with `10.0`. I couldn't found anything about SQL Server 2008.

So my question is, which one is correct? Does the version number for SQL Server 2008 start with `10.0` or `10.00`? How about SQL Server 2008 R2? Does it start with `10.5` or `10.50`?

Comment: Giving downvote without giving a reason is not fair...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this on your server

```
 SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')
```

I get 10.0.2531.0  on one server with SQL Server 2008 on it

Comment: i did and i got the same number as you do. So the two websites that I had in my question are giving wrong information?

Comment: when you go to Download the ServicepAck for this one http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=66ab3dbb-bf3e-4f46-9559-ccc6a4f9dc19&displaylang=en it actually has 00 in it

Comment: yeah, so should it be 10.0 or 10.00? Why are they inconsistent? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[How to Identify your SQL Server version and Edition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

Comment: i knew this page. I have actually had the link in my question. That doesn't explain the inconsistency with the other websites.

Comment: @StarCub: this is the **official** Microsoft site - chances are, **they** know what version they're using....

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the link in your article. But that should be THE definitive resource for determining version numbers. I'd use that over any other site.

Comment: @marc_s But two Microsoft web pages are not consistent. this one (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) says 10.0 but this one (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=66ab3dbb-bf3e-4f46-9559-ccc6a4f9dc19&displaylang=en) says 10.00.

Comment: @Andrew Lewis I was just wondering if it could be different environments that effect the version numbers from 0 to 00 or from 5 to 50.

Comment: @StarCub: in that case, you'll probably just have to deal with both possible versions, then...